# Set background color through CSS for text only with line breaks

Tags: css

How would you go about applying a background color with CSS only, while only applying the color to visible text.

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<div style="width:200px;background-color:white;">
<p style="background-color:red;color:black;">This text is longer than 200 pixel and therefore a line break will occur</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the background is applied to the full with of the `<p>`-tag and not ending with the last character before the line break occurs. On the side note, I am NOT able to line break the displayed text manually.

So if the output the above would look like this:

```
----------this line is exactly 200px----------
This text is longer than 200 pixel and
therefore a line break will occur
----------------------------------------------
```

So the background-color should end with the word "and" on the first line and end with the word "occur" on the second line, leaving the background of the `<div>` white.

I am really pulling my hair out and would love to get input if this is even possible without manually setting line breaks? I'd go with a javascript solution too, but prefer a css only one.

Comment: If you're talking about something like the white text with black background found on this page: http://31.192.226.6/work/localmarket.com/ that is created using two separate elements (a heading and a paragraph), one for each row.

Comment: ... which is not what I am intending to do. I was looking for a possibility to not have to manually separate the content for the effect to look the way I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paragraphs are block elements - they take up the width of their **containers**, not their **content**.

You need to use `<span>` instead of `<p>` to get the desired effect.

Alternately you and make `<p>` an inline element, but this may break other aspects of your page.

```
p {display:inline}
```

Comment: ok, but by using the display:inline attribute the background effect is as long as the longest line inside the element. Meaning the first line's background color is as wide as the second line (which is longer)...

Comment: Without manually tagging portions the content and formatting the text the way you want, this is the best you can do with a CSS-only approach.

Comment: any idea how to tag line ends through javascript then? there must be a solution to this, since i have seen this around on many sites and can't believe they all do it manually ...